# PHP move_uploaded_file fails with no errors

Tags: php, linux, nginx

On LEMP (Linux CentOS, Nginx, MariaDB, PHP) server, `/etc/php.ini` file has the following.

```
file_uploads = on
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Stage1.html has the following markup, which is used to select an image file, and post the image to Stage2.php.

```
<form action="Stage2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Stage2.php has the following.

```
<?php
    $original_name = $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
    $temporary_name = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
    $target = "/var/www/html/images/" . $original_name;

    if(move_uploaded_file($temporary_name, $target)) {echo "Success";}
    else{echo "Failed";}
?>
```

Original File, Temporary File, and Target are properly set. However, **Failed** is returned.

[image]

Adding the following to Stage2.php returns 0. To quote the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), 0 means "There is no error, the file uploaded with success."

```
$_FILES["upload"]["error"];
```

Adding the following to Stage2.php does not display any errors. This leads me to suspect that PHP thinks that everything is OK, and perhaps the problem is some issue with CentOS or Nginx. Is this the logical assumption?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For debugging, in CentOS, I've set the permissions of /tmp and /var/www/html/images to 777 (read, write, execute for everybody). Still no errors are returned.

[image]

Comment: check your max_upload_file_size

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` is 2 MB, and the file being uploaded is 40 KB.

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($original_name , $target)) try this once and check @JeremyCanfield

Comment: `if(move_uploaded_file($original_name, $target))` also produces Failed, because the `move_uploaded_file` function moves the temporary file to the target directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case others run into this problem, I want to share what I discovered. I was able to conclude this was an issue with Linux CentOS, and not a PHP issue.

Typically, `open_basedir` will be set to `/var/www` in `/etc/php.ini`. In this scenario, `upload_tmp_dir` must be somewhere below `/var/www`. I set `upload_tmp_dir` to `/var/www/html/images/tmp`.

```
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/html/images/tmp
```

I then set the temporary uploads directory permission is 755.

```
[john.doe@server1 ~]# chmod 755 /var/www/html/uploads/tmp
```

I then used the following PHP to determine what user PHP uses to upload the file. In my scenario, the user was **apache**.

```
<?php
    echo exec('whoami'); 
?>
```

Once I had determined the user was apache, I set the owner of the temporary uploads directory to apache.

```
[john.doe@server1 ~]# chown apache:root /var/www/html/uploads/tmp
```

Lastly, I had to set the SELinux context of the temporary and permanent uploads directory to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`.

```
[john.doe@server1 ~]# chcon --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/uploads
[john.doe@server1 ~]# chcon --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/uploads/tmp
```

After doing these things, I was then able to upload files using PHP.

Comment: FYI I also needed to `chcon --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /tmp`

Answer (score 1):

In this case im able to upload file successfully!
Just run following command in your terminal

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/directoryPath
```

---

Note : OS centOS 7,Apache2.4.6